# Is there a UI for editing Jira email templates?

Tags: email, templates, jira

Once Jira user create a ticket, there will be a notification email send to the reporter and assignee, and the mail subject might be "[Jira]".
I know we can modify the related template files to customise the subject, but it takes more effort to do that. Is there a UI for Jira administrator or user conveniently edit the email template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to be able to update the [Jira] prefix in the subject of the notification emails then you can do that in the ["Outgoing Mail" configuration screen](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/configuring-jira-s-smtp-mail-server-to-send-notifications-185729628.html#ConfiguringJIRA'sSMTPMailServertoSendNotifications-DefineoredittheSMTPmailserver). Just enter the "Prefix" that you would like.

Any other kind of customisation is not possible within JIRA by default. There is an open feature request to add an editor for the email templates: [JRA-7266](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-7266)

There are a few add-ons that do provide functionality to configure notifications and templates in a more flexible way though. Some popular ones are [Enterprise Mail Handler](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.javahollic.jira.jemh-ui/cloud/overview) (available both for cloud and JIRA server) and [Email This Issue](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.jira.plugin.emailissue/server/overview) (only for JIRA server).